# Is "halfly" a word?

Tags: word-usage

Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=halfly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalfly%3B%2Cc0) shows that it's being used. However, some [people](http://www.answers.com/Q/Why_is_'halfly'_not_considered_a_word_in_some_English_dictionaries) disagree on the matter.

Is "halfly" a word? If not, what's an alternative?

Example sentence:

> I lied to her. Well, only halfly. I was *indeed* sick.

Comment: How do you intend to use "halfly"? As the answer points out, _half_ can be used as an adverb. Notice also that the actual result for "halfly" is about 227 on [google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=halfly). That's not very impressive. It suggests that people don't use this word.

Comment: @Max I added an example sentence. *Half* doesn't sound very well?

Comment: In my opinion, it sounds somewhat like the speaker is making a joke, or trying (hard) to be funny. "Well, only half." sounds ok to me, but I would expect "Well, only half lied." Again, this is merely an opinion.

Comment: It seems like it was in use in the past, well in past. And then it became obsolete. However, you can find some rare usage in current writing/speaking. But that is very rare.

Comment: @Man_From_India The Ngram shows the opposite?

Comment: @alexchenco: Per the OED, *halfly* went out of vogue 300+ years ago, waaaaaay before Google's Ngram corpus starts.

Comment: Sorry @Max i've only seen now that you suggested *half-lie* in your comment. If that had been posted as an answer, I would have refrained from posting a reply.

Comment: Is-this-*really*-a-word questions are never productive. There's no definitive list of English words. Some people will say it's fine, others will say it isn't.

Comment: If your desire is to be idiomatic, you'd say something like "I lied to her. Well, it was only half a lie. I really was sick." https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+a+lie%2Ca+half+lie&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalf%20a%20lie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20half%20lie%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OED tells us that it is an *adverb* with the meaning of "half", but that it is obsolete:

> **Obs**.
>     = half *adv*.
>
> <sup>c1480  (▸a1400)    *St. Ninian* 1418 in W. M. Metcalfe *Legends Saints Sc. Dial*. (1896) II. 344   Til hyme, þat halfly-slepand lay.
>
>   1565   J. Hall *Hist. Expost.* in tr. *Lanfranc Most Excellent Woorke Chirurg*. sig. Dddv,   Thine arte is halflye wunne.
>
>   1622   M. Drayton *2nd Pt. Poly-olbion* xxiv. 83   So holy that him there, they halfely deifide.
>
>   1674   N. Fairfax *Treat. Bulk & Selvedge* 167   This is what it is halfly.</sup>

The most recent citation is from 1674, but it has happened before that words thought to be obsolete are revived or evolve anew from familiar forms. If ***singly*** and ***on(e)ly*** are adverbs, it is no stretch to grant ***halfly*** the same label.

Answer (score 4):

Technically speaking, *halfly* is a word.

It is made up of letters, it looks English, its meaning is easily recognizable, and it even has some history (see @P. E. Dant's answer)

If  the OP is writing a story, I see no reason why he cannot use the word *halfly* in his narration, it's called artistic licence; English poets, scholars, and hack writers have been manipulating and twisting English words ever since the Dark Ages.

Authors such as W. Shakespeare, Lewis Carroll and J.R.R. Tolkien had the confidence and the competence  to "invent" words whenever the occasion arose. Indeed, Caroll coined the expression ***portmanteau word***, which has long been recorded as a "proper" word. George Orwell, in his novel 1984, coined several expressions that have entered the English lexicon: ***doublethink***, and ***newspeak*** are but two.

The OP asked whether "halfly" was a word.

> I lied to her. Well, only *halfly*. I was indeed sick.

If halfly is italicized,  readers will accept, and interpret it as being artistic license. It also sounds like something a schoolboy would say to justify a lie.

All in all, I think *halfly* is effective, it achieves what it sets out to do. An alternative might be **white lie**, but it doesn't quite convey the same impish charm, or meaning.

> **[white lie](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/white_lie)**
>   A harmless or trivial lie, especially one told to avoid hurting someone's feelings.
>   ‘when I was young, I told little white lies’

As I was writing, it suddenly occurred to me that the compound ***half-lie*** is a perfect fit. (It has already been suggested by [@Max](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106570/is-halfly-a-word#comment212653_106570))

> **[half-lie](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/half-lie)**
>   something that a person says or writes that they know to be partly untrue
>   ⇒ *I tried to convince myself that to change a tense was to tell no more than a half-lie*.

Transforming the original sentence into

> I lied to her. Well, only *half-lied*. I was indeed sick

Thanks to @martha, in the comments below, who has suggested that the words *half*, *half way*, and *partly* could work equally well.

Comment: In the OP's example sentences, *halfly* could be effectively replaced by *half*, *half way*, or *partly*.

Answer (score 1):

> halfly

has the meaning "only half as much" or "not fully", just as

> fully

means full.

> I halfly said yes to their invitation.
>   *I half heartedly accepted their invitation*

Comment: In your example, *half-heartedly*,  doesn't mean "not fully", it's closer to reluctantly, and lacking in enthusiasm. The speaker prefers not to accept the invitation but probably feels obliged.

Comment: The question is asking about *half**l**y*, not *halfy*. That makes this NAA. Also where are your references and evidence to back up your answer???

Comment: "Halfy" is not in https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&query=halfy. If "halfy" a typo for "halfly" here?

Answer (score 1):

The word you want to find is:

> **partially**.

Comment: On this site, we appreciate answers that explain more thoroughly than that and also provide references.

Answer (score 0):

There is a word "half-done". You also can say "partially done".

In cases like that, if you say "halfly done", it would provoke a reaction like:

> I understand what you have said, but why have not you said it a proper way?

It is a word. But use it wisely. If you need this sort of reaction then go for it.